# Functions and Arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm learning C to develop for Linux and I'm trying to get a *sizeof()* from a array that is a function argument. The *sizeof* always returns 8 (that is the size of a pointer) so the question is, in C all the arguments are pointers? If don't what is wrong this piece of code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int println(char text[]);

int main()
{
        char text[] = "Helloabc";
        int x = println(text);
        x = x + 48;
        char y[] = { (char)x };
        printf("%s\n", y);
        return 0;
}

int println(char text[])
{
        int size = sizeof(text) / sizeof(text[0]);
        int size1 = sizeof(text);
        int size2 = sizeof(text[0]);
        printf("%i\n", size1);
        printf("%i\n", size2);
        return size;
}
```

This piece of code produces this return:

```
8
1
8Helloabc
```

It's also for some freak reason printing "Helloabc".

Comment: have you tried debugging your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Firstly, in C, not every argument is a pointer.

2) sizeof returns the size of the datatype in terms of bytes.

3) Here, size1 is the size of pointer to a character array. See Aaron's reply in the comment section. My bad. I need to brush up on my C.

4) size2 is the size of a character in the character array. Since a character takes up 1 byte, therefore size2 = 1.

5) The reason you get "8Helloabc" when you print y is because in C, strings must be null-terminated. That is, strings must end with the character '\0'. Otherwise, the printf function will not know when to "stop" reading and printing characters.

The line `char text[] = "Helloabc";` implicitly has a null character, '\0', added at the end of the array. However your code `char y[] = { (char)x };` does not.

It happens that the "Helloabc" string is stored just "after" the value for y in memory hence printf read past the value for "8" and continued printing until it reached the null character at the end of "helloabc". Sometimes you may not be so lucky and printing y may give you rubbish or a segmentation fault when the memory printf attempt to read from is not properly populated.

Simply change your code to: `char y[] = {(char) x, '\0'};` have it print out just the value of x.

Comment: "size1 = 8 (characters) x (1 byte each) = 8 (bytes)"  No, size1 is the size of a `char *`, which is 8 bytes on a 64-bit machine.  You can tell because that array is actually 9 bytes long - remember your null-bytes.

Comment: Thanks, it was the completest answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Normally an array is different from a pointer. However, when passing as an argument, an array is converted to a pointer. If you want to get the size of the array, you should pass it as another argument, or set a sentinel in the array and calculate the size manually.

As for why it's printing "Helloabc", it's because your `char y[]` has no `\0` as end of string. So when you `printf` y as a string (via `%s`), it keeps going until it finds a `\0`.

What will happen then? Mind that x, y and text are all on the stack, and the stack is from high memory to low memory. So your stack now looks like this:
[image: stack]

(I put a wrong example and find it's not the way, sorry. Now I fixed it.)

So, `printf` firstly output `0x38('8')`. Then it goes on with "Helloabc" and finally find `'\0'`.

That's why you get "8Helloabc".

Comment: Why do you think that the int `8` falls between the char `'8'` and the string `"Helloabc"`?  The print would have terminated at the first null-byte (i.e. the first byte in the int `8`).

Comment: @AaronDufour That's right, I find it's not the way, so I edit it. But I'm a little confused, how do the compiler manage the order of variables on the stack? I'll go and read more. Thank you.

Comment: @Manas It can differ wildly between compilers, but your original suggestion will basically never happen.  They prefer that multi-byte primitives start at the beginning of a word (usually 4 bytes) so you will rarely see a single char immediately followed by an int.  It would be more likely to put 3 bytes of unused buffer space between them.  However, in this case the int was probably placed first (so it lines up with the word boundary).

Answer (score 1):

When the name of an array appears as a function argument, the compiler implicitly converts it into a pointer to the array's first element. Accordingly, the corresponding parameter of the function is always a pointer to the same object type as the type of the array elements.

`int size1 = sizeof(text);` The expression `sizeof(text)` return the size of the pointer, this size depends of platform, (4 bytes) on 32-bit and (8 bytes) in 64-bit.

`int size2 = sizeof(text[0]);` Variable size2 receives size of first element of array in type `char`, whose size is 1 byte.

`char text[] = "Helloabc";` must be null terminated to be printed correctly.